# Subsets of a graph, maximal w.r.t. the property of inducing a subgraph with minimum degree at least $k$

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple undirected graph. Define an *mmd$k$s in $G$* (for 'maximal minimum degree $k$ subset') to be any subset $S$ of $V$ such that

1. the subgraph induced by $S$ in $G$ has minimum degree $\geq k$,
2. $S$ is $\subseteq$-maximal w.r.t. property 1.

Moreover, for any $k$, let $\mathrm{smmds}(G,k):=\sup\{ \lvert S \rvert \colon\text{$S$ is an mmd$k$s in $G$}\}$.

Moreover, for any class $\mathbb{G}$ of graphs, let $\mathrm{smmds}(\mathbb{G},k):=\sup\{ \mathrm{smmds}(G,k)\colon G\in\mathbb{G}\}$.

My question is whether

- *mmd$k$s*'s
- the graph invariant $\mathrm{smmds}(\cdot,k)$,

have already been analysed and named in graph theory.

I am interested in understanding how $\mathrm{smmds}(\cdot,k)$, varies, as a function of $k$, for different families of graphs (or certain random graph models).

Comment: Try the following.  Set G to G_0.  Given G_n, find and remove all the vertices (and corresponding edges) in G_n of lowest degree, and call what's left G_{n+1}.  For many G, the progression of graphs G_n will see an increase in the graph parameter minimal degree.  I think when this parameter hits k, G_n will be your S_k.  You might look at degree sequences and processes of building or deconstructing graphs.  Gerhard " Doesn't Know Technical Graph Terminology" Paseman, 2017.08.16.

Comment: Dear @Ozzy: I think there were so many infelicities and malapropisms in the original formulation of the OP that a complete (meaning-preserving) rewrite of the OP was in order. If you have reasons to prefer some of your formulations, please say so, and/or roll back. Documenting all my changes would get too long: only so much: 'network' *tends* to be used in a specific, quite different sense nowadays, 'agents' is not usual graph theoretic language. There were *logical* issues too with the OP, too.

Comment: Dear @Ozzy: a published article extremely relevant to your question (though not explicitly addressing precisely what you seem to be asking for) is [Daniela Kühn, Deryk Osthus: Partitions of graphs with high minimum degree or connectivity. Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B. Volume 88, Issue 1, May 2003, Pages 29-43](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895603000285)

Comment: @PeterHeinig, to me, that paper doesn't seem to be relevant. I've added a link to a more relevant one in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)#k-Cores), a *$k$-core* of a graph $G$ is a maximal connected subgraph $K$ of $G$ such that every vertex of $K$ has degree at least $k$. Apart from the "connected" part of the definition, this is the same as your set $S_k$. Your set $S_k$ is the union of the vertex sets of all $k$-cores of $G$.

Similar to what Gerhard suggested, you can find the set $S_k$ by initialising $S_k:=V(G)$ and then repeatedly deleting every vertex of degree less than $k$ in the subgraph induced by $S_k$ until there are no such vertices left (note that this may terminate with $S_k=\emptyset$).

With regards to $k$-cores in random graphs, one natural place to start might be  the paper [*Size and connectivity of the $k$-core of a random graph*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9190162U) by Tomasz Łuczak.

Comment: Dear @Jon Noel: this is correct. One small thing: I would not write "delete", but rather **leave out every vertex of degree less than $k$**, here (even though e.g. the Wikipedia article you link to do), since 'delete' seems to me to carry misleading connotations: one must not delete offending vertices (which would in general lower the degree of the vertices one is aiming to be left with), rather *leaves them by the wayside*. If in your (correct) algorithm, you really *deleted* the offenders from the data structure, you are losing so much information that you will not in general find the core.

Comment: @PeterHeinig, I disagree. He is not simply asking to find the set of vertices of degree at least $k$ in a graph (which would be completely trivial...), he wants a maximal set that induces a subgraph of minimum degree $k$. Therefore, it is not a bad thing that deleting vertices lowers the degree of other vertices; you simply *must* delete those vertices to obtain such a set. By the way, it is possible that this algorithm outputs the empty set, but this makes sense; $S_k$ might actually be empty.

Comment: Dear @Jon Noel, thanks, yes, you are right that one should delete the offending vertices outright (and I was misled by something which still does not seem right in the current version of your answer: you write "$S_k$ is the union of the vertex sets of the $k$-cores of the graph". This seems false for $0\text{--}1\text{--}2\text{--}3$ which has $\{1,2\}$ as its $2$-core, yet, as you correctly point out, has $S_k=\emptyset$, so here $S_k$ is *not* the union of the cores. (Btw, you should tell the OP that the only reason for non-unique cores are non-connected $G$.) Would you please clarify?

Comment: Why do you think that $\{1,2\}$ is a $2$-core in that graph (which I assume is a path on $4$ vertices)? By the way, I've realised that the $k$-core is actually clearly unique (the disconnected thing doesn't actually matter). I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Dear @Jon Noel: thanks for the answer. Re your question: the reason is simply, as I now realized, I have heretofore worked with an apparently less usual definition of 'core', which has 'degree'='degree within the ambient graph'. For several reasons (among them: I understand that one should not excessively chat here), I will now go offline and leave you to clarify whatever you think there is to clarify. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: To make things more explicit, write the k-core of G as K, and note that every vertex in K has degree at least k (in K as well as in G).  The current reading allows one to take K out of context, and allow vertices of K to have had degree k in G, not necessarily degree k in K.  Gerhard "Cake Or K Core Or..." Paseman, 2017.08.17.

Comment: Dear @JonNoel. It turns out that k-cores are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the pointers!